# Getting the name or id of an input, not the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question.

```
<input type="text" value="Some text" name="thisname" id="thisid" />
```

How can I get the name of the id or name that is being used, instead of value.
It is clear that value of this text-box is "Some text". But what I want is name of id and name being used now.

To be more clear ... I want "thisid" or "thisname".

See my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").parent(".selected").css("background", "#FF8877");

});

function add(name) {
    $("#" + name).parent().clone().insertAfter($("#" + name).parent());
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div><p>Hello</p></div>
<div class="selected"><p name="name" id="name" onclick="add(this.name)">Hello Again</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: What's the name of id? they are two distinct attributes.. Please review your question..

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a greeting, like "Hello Again Keesher", is that right? Are you trying to store the user's name or the user's ID in the HTML attributes `name` and `id`? If so, it's a coincidence that you're trying to store someone's name and there's also an HTML attribute called `name`. You should store the user's name or ID in the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your edited question. You're doing it wrong.

It'd be much simpler to pass a reference to the element, and not it's name.

js:

```
function add(element) {
    $(element).parent().clone().insertAfter($(element).parent());
}
```

html:

```
<p name="name" id="name" onclick="add(this)">Hello Again</p>
```

If you want to know why your code didn't work:

"id" and "name" are 2 different attributes. In CSS (and therefore in jquery) you generally select an element by ID, with this syntax: `#idOfElement`. If you really have to, you could select one or more elements by name: `*[name="nameOfElement"]`.

this gives you 2 options:

- pass to your original `add` function the id, not the name:

  ```
  <p name="name" id="name" onclick="add(this.id)">Hello Again</p>
  ```
- change your add function to work with names instead

  ```
  function add(name) {
      $('*[name="' + name + '"]').parent().clone().insertAfter($('*[name="' + name + '"]').parent());
  }
  ```

Anyway, passing a reference of the element itself, is still the best option.

Comment: I will try to use your suggestion.

Comment: Keesher, if this solved your problem accept this answer please

Answer (score 18):

So, assuming that you have `var input` set to your element:

- `input.value` gives you the value
- `input.id` gives you the id
- `input.name` gives you the name

Answer (score 3):

if you are using jQuery

```
$(this).attr('name'); //for name
$(this).attr('id'); //for ID
```

Comment: Given that `this` refers to the element... You can't run this everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

if yo use jquery you can do the follwing:

```
$('#thisid').attr('name');
```

Comment: I presume that if he wants to know "thisid" he can't really use that as a selector. 
Altough, of course, it's not a good practice to change the id of an element, and therefore it shouldn't be necessary to "find" the id of an element...